# Confluent Kafka-connect-JDBC connector showing hexa decimal data in the kafka topic

Tags: jdbc, apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect, confluent-platform, confluent-schema-registry

I'm trying to copy the data from a table in the oracle db and trying to put that data in a kafka topic. I've used the following JDBC source connector for that :

```
name=JDBC-DB-source
connector.class=io.confluent.connect.jdbc.JdbcSourceConnector
connection.password = *******
connection.url = jdbc:oracle:thin:@1.1.1.1:1111/ABCD
connection.user = *****
table.types=TABLE
query= select * from (SELECT * FROM JENNY.WORKFLOW where ID = '565231')

key.converter=io.confluent.connect.avro.AvroConverter
key.converter.schema.registry.url=http://localhost:8081

value.converter=io.confluent.connect.avro.AvroConverter
value.converter.schema.registry.url=http://localhost:8081

mode=timestamp+incrementing
incrementing.column.name=ID
timestamp.column.name=MODIFIED

topic.prefix=workflow_data12
poll.interval.ms=6000
timestamp.delay.interval.ms=60000

transforms:createKey
transforms.createKey.type:org.apache.kafka.connect.transforms.ValueToKey
transforms.createKey.fields:ID
```

So far good. I'm able to get the data into my kafka topic. But the output looks like the following :

```
key - {"ID":"\u0001"}   
value - {"ID":"\u0001","MODIFIED":1874644537368}
```

You can observer that my key "**ID**" is being printed as Hexadecimal format, despite I'm using Avro in my JDBC properties file.

(I'm using **kafka-avro-console consumer** to view the data on the command line)

(And the column "ID" is of type "**NUMBER**" in the oracle db.)

Could anyone help me to point out if I'm missing some property? to print the data properly in Avro format.

Thanks in advance!!

Answer (score 0):

Add this property to your .properties file e.g before query:

**numeric.mapping=best_fit**

Detail Explanation can be found [here](https://www.confluent.io/blog/kafka-connect-deep-dive-jdbc-source-connector)

Answer (score 0):

Yes, use numeric.mapping=best_fit if your data type is NUMERIC as Muhammad Arslan Akhtar said.

And if your data type is DECIMAL, you have to firstly CAST that column in your query like below because numeric.mapping=best_fit is no use for DECIMAL.

```
select CAST(Price AS NUMERIC(18,4)) as Price from xxx
```